# sifr throwing 'G.brokenFlashIE' is null or not an object error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sifr

We are getting this error occurring randomly throughout the site, but only on one computer that we've noticed so far. We have not gone live with our site (it's in the QA phase) and only one person testing this site seems to be having this issue come up. Here is the error message:

---

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Mon, 11 Jan 2010 15:33:03 UTC

Message: 'G.brokenFlashIE' is null or not an object
Line: 17
Char: 24003
Code: 0

---

They're running IE8 on XP/SP3. sifr is on every page in the site, yet this error shows up inconsistently. The person this is happening to says it happens frequently, but randomly.

It works fine for every other browser/OS combination we've tried.

We are at the end of our testing phase and need to go live very soon. Any help/suggestion/resolution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had only a handful of reports on this, nobody really got back with any details. Your error message helps in that regard.

I can track the error back to some cleanup code that is run when the page is unloaded. My impression is that this cleanup code is called twice — the first execution sets `G = null` causing the error on the second execution. Aside from an IE bug, the only possible reason the cleanup code *might* be called twice is if the user stops the page from loading. Is this what is going on?

Comment: I will ask if they are stopping the page from loading. But from what I understand, no, they are not. I should add that this is an ektron (cms) driven site - not sure if that helps or changes anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've isolated when this error occurs. I haven't found out why but I have been manage to stop it happening. I'm running IE7.

It fires only when my url contains a `20%` space separating a parameter AND a `#` at the end of the URL and then I click a flash link. No other combination.

e.g) `page.php?st=wv&stn=West%20Virginia#` - take the `#` off the end and its all fine.

The # appears because I have to had to open a dropdown menu on the same with a blank 'a href' link, hence the '#' at the end of the url. I have removed the whole `href='#'` from the link - which seems to work accross the browsers.

If this helps anyone at all I'll be so happy as in 14 years of web development its bugged me that Ive never been able to give back and solve a forum problem!